# Typescript can't create interface for catch(err)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am using node with mongoose. After logging error, I thought "Well, lets just return array of errors by accessing Object.keys(err)".

I wrote external function with param data defined by interface:

```
export interface mongoError {
    errors: errors
}

interface errors {
    [index: string]: Object
}

getError = (err: mongoError) => {
    ...
    Object.keys(err.errors).forEach(....
}
```

And I am sending data to it by:

```
    mongooElement = new element(this.data)
    try {
        await mongooElement.save()
        return NewItem
    } catch (err) {
        return this.getError(err)
    }
```

I am always getting error after I try to change type of err in catch:

> **Catch clause variable type annotation must be any or unknown if specified ts(1196)**

Comment: Did you try adding a type annotation to `err`?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes. Without anything in catch but with error defined in getError, typescript show me error that any cant be Object. But as soon as I add type to err "mongoError", it show me error which is at the bottom of this post. Right now I am using "any" and I can't figure out, how to make it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20024

That issue is still active and as far as I can tell using type annotations on catch is not possible.

However since typescript 4 it's allowed `catch(error: unknown)` to be used.

There's also: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8677#issuecomment-220385124

Explaining that using types on errors is very difficult because even if you try and cast it or check it, you still can't be sure if it was some random system memory error (or something) instead of the one you're expecting.  So even if you do some sort of check on `MongoError`, it suddenly throws you a system memory error and that defeats the point of using a type on the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to know at compile type what the the type of `err` is since virtually anything can be thrown, and you can't tell ahead of time what causes the catch to be triggered. I think this is what the error you're getting from TS is.

If you want to deal with a specific error type, consider using a runtime check, for example using `instanceof`, that will help TS know what type you're dealing with, and also help your code be more robust just in case you get a different type of error e.g.:

```js
mongooElement = new element(this.data)
    try {
        await mongooElement.save()
        return NewItem
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof MongoError) {
           // here typescript knows that err is definitely a `MongoError`
           return this.getError(err)
        } else {
          handleOtherError(err);
        }
    }
```

One caveat with this is that, since `instanceof` is actually runtime check (not a TS keyword), `MongoError` has to be a concrete type (e.g. an actual class that exists in the compiled JS code and at runtime), not just a Typescript interface. I believe the node js mongodb library has a `MongoError` defined, not sure if the same is accessible through `mongoose`.